# Python Matplotlib Graphics not Displaying in Rstudio Plot Panel

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, backend

I'm trying to plot matplotlib graphics in RStudio plot panel.

I'm using R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) (Funny-Looking Kid), RStudio 2022.02.0 Build 443 and Python 3.9.13

My code in Python is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
mpl.use("TkAgg", force=True)
x = np.linspace(0,100,101)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Instead of getting the resulting plot in the RStudio plots panel, it opens in a separated window.

I have tried tweaking RStudio Global Options by choosing specific backends like Cairo and Agg and / or switching the matplotlib backend to "TkCairo" or "WebAgg". The result is always the same: the plot is shown in a separated window instead of RStudio Plot Panel.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution just by chance. Since I'm studying quantum computing I'm also working with QuTip. I noticed that if I load Qutip BEFORE pyplot, the graphics are shown in the plot panel. The working code can be seen below:

```
import qutip as qt 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[1,4,9,16,25])
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

QuTip must be loading several other packages by itself, because now it is not even necessary to select the graphics backend as before (I was using "TkAgg").

What I'd like to know is what exactly is QuTip (version 4.7.0) doing so to get such behavior. Anyhow the solution has been "found".